# Checking if a SoundCloud song is embeddable

Tags: php, soundcloud

I'm trying to use the SoundCloud API to check if a song is embeddable, is this the same as streamable? My code looks like this:

```
$trackid = $track['id'];
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($track['user']['username']);
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($track['title']);
$downloadable = $track['downloadable'];
$streamable = $track['streamable'];

        // Check if streamable
        if(!$streamable) {

        header( 'Location: error.php' );

        } else { ...
```

I can get the trackid, username, title & downloadable easily, but is streamable the correct property to look for? I'm talking about when you go to embed a song and it says "Oops this track can't be played outside of SoundCloud." I want to make sure this doesn't happen and unallow a song if it's one of those songs.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the [documentation](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/tracks) the `streamable` proprety exists. And yes it's the right one.